# Напиши, в чём(,) ему(,) проблема

Tags: пунктуация

Понятно всё насчёт этих двух предложений.

`Напиши, в чём проблема, ему.`

`Напиши ему, в чём проблема.`

Но в этом, ниже то бишь написанном, как нам быть?

`Напиши, в чём(,) ему(,) проблема.`

Comment: я предложу вариант: ему чем в напиши проблема